# Is the fundamental group of a retract a subgroup of the original space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a retract of $X$. Is the fundamental group of $A$ a subgroup of the fundamental group of $X$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $i$ be the inclusion and $r$ the retraction, so that $r\circ i$ is the identity. Then $(r\circ i)_*=r_*\circ i_*$ is the identity. Thus $r_*$ is surjective and $i_*$ is injective. From the latter fact we deduce that the fundamental group of the retract is isomorphic to a subgroup of the fundamental group of the larger space.